# Error when import Sklearn with anaconda python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, anaconda

I try to use

`import sklearn`

But I get the error message at following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------  
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7e12b462961d> in <module>()
    1 
----> 2 import sklearn

~/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py in 
<module>()
148                'clone']
149 
--> 150     from .daal4sklearn import dispatcher
151     dispatcher.enable()
152 

~/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/daal4sklearn/dispatcher.py in <module>()
  7 from ..linear_model.ridge import Ridge
  8 
----> 9 from .k_means import fit as kmeans_fit
 10 from .pca import _fit_full as pca_fit_full
 11 from .pairwise import daal_pairwise_distances

~/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/daal4sklearn/k_means.py in <module>()
  5 from ..cluster.k_means_ import k_means
  6 from ..externals.six import string_types
----> 7 from .utils import getArrayFromNumericTable, make_csr_table, make_HomogenNumericTable
  8 from daal.data_management import CSRNumericTable
  9 from daal.data_management import 
HomogenNumericTable,HomogenNumericTable_Float32,HomogenNumericTable_Intc

~/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/daal4sklearn/utils.py in <module>()
  1 import numpy as np
  2 from scipy import sparse as sp
----> 3 from daal.data_management import readOnly, NumericTableIface, BlockDescriptor, BlockDescriptor_Float32, packed_mask
  4 from daal.data_management import HomogenNumericTable, HomogenNumericTable_Float32, HomogenNumericTable_Intc, CSRNumericTable
  5 

~/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/daal/__init__.py in <module>()
 55                 fp.close()
 56             return _mod
---> 57     _daal = swig_import_helper()
 58     del swig_import_helper
 59 else:

~/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/daal/__init__.py in swig_import_helper()
 51         if fp is not None:
 52             try:
---> 53                 _mod = imp.load_module('_daal', fp, pathname, description)
 54             finally:
 55                 fp.close()

~/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
241                 return load_dynamic(name, filename, opened_file)
242         else:
--> 243             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
244     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:
245         return load_package(name, filename)

~/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
341         spec = importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec(
342             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 343         return _load(spec)
344 
345 else:

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Monday123/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/daal/_daal.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libdaal_core.dylib
 Referenced from: /Users/Monday123/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/daal/_daal.cpython-36m-darwin.so
 Reason: image not found
```

I can see there are few similar issues but mine relate to Library not loaded: @rpath/libdaal_core.dylib. Not sure how to fix this.

Many Thanks

Comment: Seems like you are using the Intel channel for sklearn on MacOS? Have you tried to see if you had the daal package installed (not pydaal which is only the Python files, but the runtime package)?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, thanks for your help. Yeah I'm using MacOS and very new to python. what command line should I type to check daal package? If not how do I install. Actually I don't have this problem before, by some reason this week when I refresh my code it has this problem, not sure some system update impacted this

Comment: With Anaconda, it should be something like `conda install daal`. There is also a GUI for this that would list the available packages and then you can install what you need there as well.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher，Thanks, I installed daal packages and restart laptop but this issue still appears.

Comment: Can you try the default channel instead? Or the Intel Python distribution directly?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, please could you tell me how to do that? I was guessing might be channel is wrong as it works fine before just this week has this issue. Many Thanks

Comment: I also check the environment it shows                                                                
# conda environments:
#
                      *  /Users/Monday123/Downloads/anaconda
                         /Users/Monday123/Downloads/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_env
base                     /anaconda3
gensim_env               /anaconda3/envs/gensim_env